# Calculating Tukey HSD for a subset of comparisons - can I do this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

A colleague has about 50 samples, each with 2 conditions (treated and non-treated). The data is continuous and normal, and there are 3 data points in each sample-treatment combination. They'd like to know if, in each sample, the means differ between conditions. What's the best way to do this?

Their approach was to calculate a two-way ANOVA with sample and treatment as the factors followed by a Tukey. They're not interested in all pairwise comparisons, and instead just want to compare each sample between the two conditions. They downloaded an Excel plugin that apparently allows them to select a subset of comparisons and perform the Tukey on that. I thought a Tukey posthoc was restricted to all pairwise comparisons, and the Excel plugin seems sketchy, so I'm curious if they're going about it the right way. Can a Tukey posthoc test be performed on only a subset of comparisons?

My suggested approach (which avoids a dodgy Excel plugin) was to just calculate 50 t-tests and apply a Bonferroni or other multiple comparison correction. Would this be better than their approach?

Edit: I found a few places saying something like "If all pairwise comparisons are of interest, Tukey has the edge. If only a subset of pairwise comparisons are required, Bonferroni may sometimes be better." [Ref1](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc47.htm) [Ref2](http://statistica.mooo.com/OneWay_Anova_with_TukeyHSD) But it's not clear whether Tukey *can* do a subset. Sorry, it seems simple, but I'm not used to working with Tukey.

Edit: Another [reference](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter13.pdf): "Tukey should be used when the only post-hoc testing is among all pairs of population means." Does this mean it *can't* be used when testing a subset of the pairs of means?

Edit: A [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/do-only-certain-pairwise-comparisons-after-significant-interaction-in-two-way-an?rq=1), although I don't see an answer.

Edit: A sentence from the [Scheffe wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_method) that seems to say that Tukey can be performed on a subset of comparisons: "If only a fixed number of pairwise comparisons are to be made, the Tukey–Kramer method will result in a more precise confidence interval. In the general case when many or all contrasts might be of interest, the Scheffé method is more appropriate..." Now I'm very confused!

Comment: This should work: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/multcomp/docs/glht.

Comment: @D_Williams Thanks! Although I'm not really looking for an implementation, since I'm comfortable with that in Matlab. Instead I'm wondering if it's possible for Tukey to do anything other than all pairwise comparisons. From your links and other references it seems like the answer is no, but I haven't seen it said explicitly (only implicitly).

Comment: I avoid correcting for multiple comparisons by using a hierarchical Bayesian approach for even simple problems. For me, the presence of an effect should not depend on how many, or the order in which, multiple comparisons we calculated. From my recollection of frequentist approaches, however, you could say you preplanned specific comparisons, then do only those comparisons with the method of your choice. I am not sure about the Tukey methods as it concerns subsets, sorry.

Comment: I am honestly not sure. Why does it have to be the Tukey method?

Comment: I'm a new employee and I want to make sure I have a good reason to correct their approach, which is the Tukey method. I think all signs point to them doing it wrong, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Gotcha. From Wikipedia, it seems the Tukey hsd is for all pairwise comparisons.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test